# Is the managed package last updated date available?

Tags: managed-package, package-install, upgrade

I'm chasing a bug that I believe is fixed in the latest version of our managed package. I have a date/time for the invalid data but it is unclear whether our customer upgraded before or after that.

Is there a way to pin down the date/time of a managed package upgrade? Seeing this unimplemented idea [Show managed package upgrade history and details](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000Bq78AAC) I fear there isn't...